# Get MenuItem in lower Android versions

Tags: android, exception, menu, nullpointerexception, menuitem

I would like to get the MenuItem in lower Android versions. This code works fine in Android 4.0.3:

```
_menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).setVisible(true);
```

But the app crashes in Android 2.3.6. It throws a NullPointerException.

How can I get it work in lower Android versions?

Answer (score 0):

My code is working for a minSdkVersion of 8, and have no problems

For fragments:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_result_search, menu);

        MenuItem saveItem = menu.findItem(R.id.save_item);      
        saveItem.setVisible(false);

}
```

For Activities:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);

        MenuItem upIconActionBar = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_up);
        upIconActionBar.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Comment: I am saving the menu Object as a variable. It should be outside onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: I tested outside the onCreateOptionsMenu on a 2.3.3 android phone and it works ok, no crash

MenuItem save = mMenu.findItem(R.id.save_item); 
save.setVisible(false);

Comment: From the Android Developer doc:

If you've developed your application for Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls onCreateOptionsMenu() to create the options menu when the user opens the menu for the first time. If you've developed for Android 3.0 and higher, the system calls onCreateOptionsMenu() when starting the activity, in order to show items to the action bar.

Make sure you're not trying to access the menu on 2.3.3 before open it for the first time!

Comment: I am using onPrepareOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) to update the UI. I can call this method by calling ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(this); It works fine and seems to be the best solution.